Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region Issue
I am trying to access the IBM ICOS S3 bucket to store the files from my Java code as below.
The name of the bucket and End Point is as below
Bucket Name: icos-abc-prod-01-abc-02
Endpoint:  https://icos.abc.us-region.internal.pqr

credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(VAL_ACCESS_KEY_ID, VAL_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
                if (1==1) {
                    log.info("Trying to get file system of S3 Compatible.");
                    S3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
                                    VAL_END_POINT_REGION, "us-east-1"))
                            .build();
                    bucketName = VAL_BUCKET_NAME;
                }

While accessing this code, I am getting error as
Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.

Can someone please help?

I'm not a java programmer, but looking here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-java
I see that the endpoints do not look like the one you provided.
Actual: private static String COS_ENDPOINT = ""; // eg "https://s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud"
Yours: Endpoint:  https://icos.abc.us-region.internal.pqr
The example provided is for a "Cross-region" endpoint that resides and distributed over us-east, us-south, ...  You can find all possible endpoints here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-endpoints  The names match the "resiliency" type and the location.
